# What would be the SQL query to delete an entry from postgres table using 2 identifiers?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

The below JSON payload is an entry in one of the column of the postgres table.
The query to delete one of the player is:

```sql
UPDATE site_content
   SET content =   
       content #- 
       COALESCE(('{playersContainer,players,' ||
                (SELECT i
                   FROM generate_series(0,
                                        jsonb_array_length(content - >
                                        'playersContainer' - >
                                        'players') - 1) AS i
                  WHERE (content - > 'playersContainer' - >
                                     'players' - > i - > 'id' = '"1"')
                 ) || '}'
                 )::text [ ],'{}');
```

What would be the query if we want to delete one of the value from the "ratings" list?
For instance, we want to delete **`rating=1`** of a player with **`id=1`**

JSON payload:

```json
{
  "playersContainer": {
    "players": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Nick",
        "teamName": "Shire Soldiers",
        "ratings": [
          1,
          5,
          6,
          9
        ],
        "assists": 17,
        "manOfTheMatches": 20,
        "cleanSheets": 1,
        "data": [
          3,
          2,
          3,
          5,
          6
        ],
        "totalGoals": 19
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a textbook example of how not to use JSON data types in a database. A (mostly) normalized design would make this task dead-simple (and cheap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already tested, the following code is working.

```
update a1 set data =
    data #- '{playersContainer,players,0,ratings,0}'
where ( 
select  (data['playersContainer']['players'])[0]['id'] ? '1' from a1)
    is true;
```

[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=37b90a4c41edb00ac878e65f3a458514)

Comment: Assuming array position 0 makes it simple. The hard part is to first determine actual array indexes.